# Sequent Calculus vs Natural Deduction

Tags: proof-writing, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

Can I prove all implication proofs like   $A \to A$    or    $A \to B \to A$   in both Sequent Calculus and Natural Deduction or just in one of them? So for $A \to A$ can I use the right implication rule in sequent calculus to prove it?

Comment: Yes; both $A \to A$ and $A \to (B \to A)$ are valid propositional formulas and thus they are provable with every proof system that is complete.

Answer (score 1):

Of course this depends on the proof rules in the two systems. But the usual formulations of sequent calculus and natural deduction for classical propositional logic are equivalent: $\varphi$ is provable with a natural deduction proof with hypotheses $\Gamma$ iff the sequent $\Gamma \vdash \varphi$ is provable.

Proving $\vdash A \to A$ in sequent calculus is almost trivial. We have $A \vdash A$, and now use implication introduction.

See e.g. [Relationship between sequent calculus and Hilbert systems, natural deduction, etc](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3005369/relationship-between-sequent-calculus-and-hilbert-systems-natural-deduction-et)

Comment: is there technically an infinite numbers of proofs for A→A or is there just one?

Comment: @ryanjones in mathematical logic except for some language with ground terms only such as [Herbrand logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Term_algebra#Herbrand_base) an entailed sentence may have infinite proofs, usually we require finite proofs for most propositional and first order logics you encounter. Clearly here you can have finite proof with only 2 steps needed (axiom of identity + implication right rule) in sequent calculus, similar in ND systems.